# Flutter Project Stuck at Installing in VS Code

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

When I try to run my Flutter project in VS code by clicking on "Run without Debugging", the project is stuck after it is being built:

```
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
```

I am facing this issue in my Android phone as well as emulator.

I have tried `flutter clean`, uninstalling and reinstalling the app, as well as restarting VS Code.

However, when I run `flutter run` in the terminal, the app launches fine.

Please help me resolve the issue.